# Microphone slow to activate in Firefox on Linux in Google Meet

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, audio, microphone

My company uses Google Meet almost exclusively. Those colleagues using Chrome (macOS or Linux), or Firefox on macOS have almost instant microphone activation after joining. Firefox users on Linux (a variety of distros, Arch, Ubuntu and Fedora, that I'm aware of) have significant (5..30 seconds) delay before their microphone becomes audible (when not muted, and with any physical mute switches on the mics themselves being deactivated)

I have tried searching in the Mozilla issue tracker without success, the Google help "community" pages, and wider general internet searches.

This seems to be some linux+firefox specific "bug" but I'm at a loss where to search next. Any superuser users have some insight maybe into what specific cross-section of technology choices might come together to cause such an issue?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem with macOS Catalina with Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: Filed at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1651955 - Edward, perhaps you could add your information to that bugzilla item?

Comment: In spite of the bugzilla report, we couldn't reproduce this today, so we're considering it fixed?!